# EF Core: Update thousands of records failed

Tags: exception, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core to update thousands of records from a table called MyTable. It already has 1.500.000 rows. And here is the simple code I use to update one of its property called MyProp for each record with a different value for each of them:

```
using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
      var rows = ctx.Set<MyTable>().Take(1000000).ToList(); // I only take the first 1 million rows
      int idx = 0;
      foreach (var row in rows)
      {
           row.MyProp = $"MyNewValue{idx++}";
      }
      ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I take one million rows to update them, while calling ctx.SaveChanges(), I get the following exception: ***Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0.*** (see below for the full stack trace)

I don't know why am I facing such exception, it appears if I take 1000000 rows but not if I take only 750000 for example.
I read it could be related to the timeout of the SQL server: which are listed below, but I really do not know if it is really related to one timeout and how I can find a solution. Should I divide the update into several ones and call several times SaveChanges()?

Thank you for any suggestions.

***Here are the timeouts from the MySql server:***

connect_timeout    10

delayed_insert_timeout 300

have_statement_timeout YES

innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1

innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50

innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info OFF

innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF

interactive_timeout 610

lock_wait_timeout   31536000

net_read_timeout    30

net_write_timeout   60

rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000

slave_net_timeout   60

thread_pool_idle_timeout    60

wait_timeout    610

***Here is the full stacktrace:***
From Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update                                                                : ERROR An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MyDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Failed to read the result set.
---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0.
at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.ProtocolUtility.DoReadPayloadAsync(BufferedByteReader bufferedByteReader, IByteHandler byteHandler, Func`1 getNextSequenceNumber, ArraySegmentHolder`1 previousPayloads, ProtocolErrorBehavior protocolErrorBehavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Protocol\Serialization\ProtocolUtility.cs:line 462
at MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.StandardPayloadHandler.ReadPayloadAsync(ArraySegmentHolder`1 cache, ProtocolErrorBehavior protocolErrorBehavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Protocol\Serialization\StandardPayloadHandler.cs:line 37
at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 665

Comment: So, it is known weakness of EF. And there are a lot of solutions how to do that without ChangeTracker via third party libraries.

Comment: Thank you but why is it sending me this error? What is the weakness you re talking about? I search for Bulk libraries, but they are not free of charge. I will try to use direct raw statement using FromSqlRaw as you mentioned in your following response. Thanks

Comment: Update question that you need to update records with different values. There is not so much libraries that can do that.

Comment: I updated the question, but am I right that if I use FromSqlRaw to update 1 million records, I will need to call FromSqlRaw 1 million times because I cannot write a single update SQL query to update 1 millions records with different values at once, except if I need to insert 1 million records, because I can do insert into a single sql query?

Comment: Exactly, will prepare sample how to update million records fast as it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such update better to use temporary table which will hold new values. Then normally records should be updated by join to temporary table.

There is extension for EF Core [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators). It will add temporary tables support to LINQ queries and make possible to do such update without leaving type-safe LINQ.

```cs
// definition of temporary table structure
class IntermediateTable
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string MyProp {get; set;}
}
```

```cs
var items = ... // some input list
var rowsToUpdate = items.Select(x => new IntermediateTable 
{
    Id = x.Id,
    MyProp = x.MyProp
});

using var ctx = new MyDbContext();
using var db = ctx.CreateLinqToDBConnection();

// here all records are populated to database as fast as possible
using var tempTable = db.CreateTempTable(rowsToUpdate, 
   options: new BulkCopyOptions { BulkCopyType = BulkCopyType.ProviderSpecific },
   tableName: "SomeTempTableName");

// preparing update query
var queryToUpdate = 
    from x in ctx.Set<MyTable>()
    join t in tempTable on x.Id equals t.Id
    select new {x, t};

queryToUpdate
    .Set(u => u.x.MyProp, u => u.t.MyProp)
    .Update();
```

At the end Temporary Table will be dropped automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For your usecase since you want to set an explicit value you can execute some direct sql that will not return any rows on the server.

Read into [this nice chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) and you can actually just translate the whole operation over to a simple sql statement that will run on db only.
The paging ( skip ) part will be moved to the database, no data will be retrieved saving performance and the whole operation will not consume memory on the server

Comment: What of this chapter is interesting? How to execute Raw SQL?

Comment: Hi  @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to send an SQL statement using .FromSqlRaw method. But in fact, I need to update all 'MyProp' properties from the entities with different values, so I guess I have to send 1 million FromSqlRaw instruction with each a different 'UPDATE MyTable Set MyProp='Value for EntityX''? And I have also to do lots of insertion, I will try with FromSqlRaw, but as we can insert multiple records within  single INSERT INTO statement, I think I will be able to call only once FromSqlRaw. Am I right?

Comment: Hi @MKougiouris, Thanks I will try to use FromSqlRaw method. What is the paging (skip) part you are talking about?  If I want to update 1 millions records with 1 million different value, I must call 1 million times 'FromSqlRaw' with differente 'UPDATE MyTable SET MyProp='MyValueXX', am I right? But if I need to insert (or delete) 1 million records, I just need to call FromSqlRaw once because I can specify several records inside the same SQL INSERT INTO instruction, am I right? Thank you anyway for your response

Comment: If you want to mass update many objects its better to write an sql query for that and execute it directly. That been said its up to you if you need 1 or 2 or 3 queries to do so... On TSL you can update-by-case on a query so its doable even in that way ( a bit ugly though ). By skip i meant take sorry for that